# Infopath Form not generating email from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I created an infopath form that submits to a list, that portion works with the custom rules or with the single rule. I can't get the e-mail function to work with the customer rules, or with the singular rules.

I've searched endlessly and I seem to keep coming up with needing to enable e-mails on sharepoint and create an email server. Is this really necessary? Is there no other work around for it to generate an email short of creating an email server to generate it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yes. This is a requirement. In order for any application to send an email you must specify the mail server it is to send from.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks for the info!

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you do not want to do this?

Comment: Less technical, more red tape, I don't have that level of access so I'm going to have to put in a ticket to request someone does it for me. I'd prefer to not have to wait, but if that's what has to be done, that's what has to be done.